# Is there anyway to interpolate from within JSON in an XCode Objective-C project?

Tags: objective-c

I have some JSON which contains names of classes for instantiation, and I am trying to avoid typos causing things to blow up.

I am wondering if there is anyway I can interpolate strings or constants inside the JSON so that it can be less error prone...

For example:

```
{ "stuff": [
           { "class": "foo" } ] }
```

If this were ruby and I could make this file.json.erb would be able to do something like:

```
{ "stuff": [
           { "class": "<%= FOO_CONSTANT %>" }] }
```

...

I am wondering if there's any way I can do something remotely similar with XCode and Objective-C

Comment: What sort of object are you starting with, all the major JSON libraries for ObjC will convert an object to JSON

Comment: I am starting with literally a .json file..

Comment: by the way, your array is left open here. (well, was, I fixed it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If you must

You would be best of using a ready made template library if you insist on (or are somehow forced into) using a JSON text string.

**GRMustache** https://github.com/groue/GRMustache is a Mustache templating library for ObjC, and is fine for generating non HTML/XML, since it's really just a dumb string interpolator. Plenty of docs on the GRMustache page, and [Mustache.js](http://mustache.github.com/) will explain itself (although in an HTML centric way.)

Ultimately you can:

```
{ "stuff": [
       { "class": "{{ FOO_CONSTANT }}" } ] }
```

On the other hand there is **DMTemplates** https://github.com/mierau/DMTemplates which is a more generalised templating library.

Example template syntax in this NSString literal:

```
engine.template = @"{ \"stuff\": [\n { \"class\": \"<? FOO_CONSTANT />\" } ] }";
```

You supply it values via a dictionary, it also has a few nice features like `foreach` loops and even function calls to fill in values. Of course the template can sit in a unicode text file and be read in an interpreted at runtime instead of a hard string.

Finally, I noticed that the M4 template/macro language hasn't received much love in the ObjC world, it's an old workhorse for many C / C++ programmers for generating text. (designed by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie, who you may know of.) It may be of educational value to see a really old templating library, and the features it has (it's about 40 years old now)

However, I think **DMTemplate** is the "it just works" solution you want. (those `{{ braces }}` in Mustache would make me nervous working with JSON too.)

By the way there's also MGTemplate engine, but it uses the double brace thing again, so not really good for generating JSON.

## Ideally?

Well, I'd recommend you jack in this build a JSON string with a templating engine nonsense, and build a collection of NSDictionary / NSArray objects and serialise them with `NSJSON` or any other popular ObjC JSON library, so you eliminate any formatting/quoting error rubbish. Ultimately whatever you're doing is starting out as data, so that's really the way to handle it, the idea of transport formats like JSON is not to write them by hand, unless someone is holding a gun to your head, (but it's nice if they can be pretty-printed so you can read them.) So... er, do that, right? Right.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: GRMustache author here. I just want to say that Mustache allows you to replace the default interpolation delimiters with your own, and render, for instance, `{{=<% %>=}}{ "class": "<% CLASS %>" }`. You can avoid the weird braces clash.

Comment: This is easy to achieve in DMTemplate, just set `beginProcessorMarker` and `endProcessorMarker`

Answer (score 0):

Can you go through the key names and replace them before parsing? Something like:

```
NSMutableString *jsonString = …;

NSDictionary *environment = @{
    @"FOO_CONSTANT" : @"foo"
};

for (NSString *key in [environment allKeys]) {
    NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%= %@ %>", key];
    [jsonString replaceOccurrencesOfString:pattern withString:environment[key]];
}
```

Of course, this assumes that the keys and values are plain alphabet strings so that you can’t break the JSON syntax.